# Printout of a html diagram in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, printing

I'd like to share with you my problem with printing a html page in Internet Explorer (all versions).

I have a diagram, that needs to be printed in IE7. The diagram is several pages length, so I have cut it to thin windows, that can be fit (by a slider) to the A4 size. It works perfect in Chrome and FF. But in IE i get only bottom part of the diagram printed. That part is being printed on the top of the page, starting from page No. 2. Additionally IE ignores my printing settings (printing horizontal). I set it by:

```
@media print {

    @page {
        size: landscape;
    }
}
```

in my css.

I attach documents from FF (from Chrome is the same) and IE.

[Printout from Firefox](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxUIiJNt7Z17SGlRRTYyWXFraGc/edit?usp=sharing)
[Printout in IE10](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxUIiJNt7Z17Tm1FemdpeE93Y1E/edit?usp=sharing)

Any ideas?

Best regards,
Mateusz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ie7 not support media queries. If you want use media queries for old version ie you must use [that](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) or check this site [media queries ie 7 -8](http://cssmatter.com/blog/ie7-and-ie8-support-for-css3-media-query/)

Comment: the printout in IE10 produces exactly the same output as in IE7. I don't think, that here comes about some media queries, because in that case, in IE10 printout should work. And it doesn't work in 10.

Comment: @MateuszMoroz - You're right, IE10 should work -- as long as it's in standards mode. It might not work if IE10 is in compatibility mode or quirks mode. You should check and make sure it's in standards mode.

Comment: Guys, you were right. After disabling compatibility mode, the diagram is being printed. Although again it looks different, than in FF or Chrome (simply said: looks ugly) - it is being printed in proper page position and with all data.

@mcmac, I'll check the links, that you attached. At least I know the reason now. Thanks for help!

Comment: Hi Folks,

The solution for me was adding mark ***media="print"*** to the include css formula:

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="css/styles.print.media.css">

Then the css for printing only are being included only in printing mode, as it is desired. The diagram is being printed (almost) correctly.

Regards,

Mateusz